# Default Value for node group input sockets is not respected outside the group

Tags: node-editor

I am hoping that I just did something incorrectly. I am creating a rather simple node group with 5 input sockets. Two of them are color, and the rest (which I am concerned about) are values.

### Here is my setup:

[image: Input Setup]

Unfortunately I can't for the life of me get the default value to be respected outside of the group when right clicking > Reset to default value.

### Here is a quick screencap:

[image: Screencap]

As you can see, **each input resets to 0 instead of what I specified.** I want the the users of this node group to be able to reset any input value to its default that I specified inside of the node group itself.

What is going on here? How can I fix this?

Comment: This is an annoying feature, if you don't mind resetting ALL the fields of the group, you can always go Add > Group > yourGroup. Otherwise the only way I can see is by python scripting.

Comment: It would appear that the 'Reset to Default Value' is flawed in that it doesn't seem to work as expected in other cases also. For example, add a 'Math' node (Add/Converter/Math) and the inputs default to 0.5. However, selecting 'Reset to Default' on those fields resets them to 0.0 (but you would assume that their defaults were actually the 0.5 that they are created as). Perhaps this is something worth reporting to the developers as a bug - although it would be seen as very low priority, I expect.